# Force footnotes to be on same page as its text reference

Tags: css, footnotes

In CSS, I am trying to figure out if there is coding to make a footnote always be (or at least begin) on the same page as its corresponding number in the body. I'm currently experiencing in a program (Pressbooks) that at times the footnote shows up on the page following its number in the body. This occurs when the footnote number is anywhere on the last four lines of the body. Any coding you might suggest to fix?

Here is the relevant coding:

```
@page {
  @footnotes {
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width:thin;
    border-top-color:black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.5em; } }

.footnote {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  display: footnote;
  display: prince-footnote;
  position: footnote;
  counter-increment: footnote;
  footnote-style-position: inside;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-indent: -10px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left; }

.footnote {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  display: footnote;
  display: prince-footnote;
  prince-footnote-policy: keep-with-line;
  position: footnote;
  counter-increment: footnote;
  footnote-style-position: inside;
  margin-left: 0px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-indent: 0em;
  text-align: justify; }
```

Comment: This is not a CSS feature in e-books (which I assume this is for) and even if it were the very nature of ebook readers generally precludes it as page lengths are variable based on user settings and the device software.

Comment: This program gives options to export as an ebook, but also as pdf (for print-on-demand). I am concerned with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this comprehensive article about print design with css](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/) ([paragraph about footnotes](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/#footnotes)), you can use this CSS to move a footnote into the footnote area on the same page it's being referenced:

```
.footnote {
  float: footnote;
}
```

This is how you define footnotes the right way with CSS, however a program (browser or print preproduction application) might always misinterpret it.

Comment: I have tried this, to no avail unfortunately. Getting to my wits' end on this.

Comment: @Ryan: It's probably going to be the interpreter's "fault", or feature, then... all I can think of to at least test it is to add a ridiculous bottom margin or padding to the page layout, to see if that's what confuses the interpreter, but that's purely a guess... you could also try to add a counter to the footnotes to debug which page the interpreter thinks the respective footnote belongs to - if it's a bug in the program. At that point, you might want to contact the program manufacturer (or find someone else on SO that has experience with it - for that purpose, I'd flag your post accordingly)

Comment: I have included the coding above. I suspect you are right that it is the interpreter's fault here.